# Laravel "Find" method "Where id = ?" gives wrong result

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel 7. I have table named "Stores" and column "id" is the primary key and auto increment.

When I run `Store::find(9)->first()` it gives wrong result and when I run `Store::where('id', 9)->first()` is giving correct result.

I enable the query log and got following.

For `Store::find(9)->first()`

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from "stores" where "stores"."id" = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [
      0 => 9
    ]
    "time" => 6.41
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from "stores" limit 1"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 0.53
  ]
]
```

and for `Store::where('id', 9)->first()`

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from "stores" where "id" = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => 9
    ]
    "time" => 6.89
  ]
]
```

Comment: after calling find method no need to call again first() method .Store::find(9) equal to  Store::where('id', 9)->first()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to call `first()` with `find(id)`

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

```
//Both results will be the same

Store::find(9);

Store::where('id', 9)->first();
```